# Regex to match content after Parentheses

Tags: java, regex

I have some expressions & I need to extract all of them  say into a list

```
Example                            Output
(A + B)/(C + D)+(E / F)           {(A + B),/, (C + D), +, (E / F) }
(A + B)/(C + D)                    (A + B), /,  (C + D)
```

I need to get the operators too which are outside the parentheses.

I used this but this only gets data within the parentheses

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\(.*?\\))");
Matcher m = p.matcher(exp7);
List<String> expressions = new ArrayList<String>();
while(m.find())
{
   expressions.add(m.group());
}
```

Also if i have an expression of type

`(A / B) + C`     i need to get    `{(A / B), +, C}`

by using above pattern I can only retrieve (A / B). Can there be regex to get all the data for above mentioned type of expressions.

Comment: Never parse mathmatical expression with regex, especially with the engine that doesn't equipped with feature to do it...

Comment: @nhahtdh : Oh i can see where you are getting at. Good to know. Is there any other way to get the above output?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm

Comment: I would use something that parses math expressions, like Mathmatica.

Answer (score 0):

I know how to resolve this in two steps:

**Step1.**

search pattern:

```
(\([^\(^\)]*\)|[^\(^\)]+)
```

replace:

```
\1,
```

result:

```
(A + B)/(C + D)+(E / F)   (A + B),/,(C + D),+,(E / F),
(A + B)/(C + D)           (A + B),/,(C + D),
```

**Step 2.**

Get rid of unnecessary comma in the end.
Add '{' and '}'.

Comment: giving an error on the regex. some character is not properly escaped.

Comment: The regex is better written as `(\([^()]*\)|[^()]+)` or quoted `"(\\([^()]*\\)|[^()]+)"` but will cause problems when there are nested parenthesis, like `((A + (B))/(C + D))`

Comment: @sln : how about evaluating this expression (A / B) + C ? Could the regex be updated to evaluate above expression?

Comment: @SilentCoder Does operators always have only one character? e.g. '+', 'C' etc.

Comment: @MyDogTom: Operators would always be '+' or '/' . Rest would be expressions. 'C' would be an expression.

Comment: @SilentCoder well, try something like this: `"(\([^()]*\)|[^()\ ]{1})"` but it still not working with nested parenthesis :(

Comment: @MyDogTom: Don't bother trying to do bracket balancing with Java regex. It is simply not possible. Only PCRE, Perl, .NET regex can do that.